# How to set 'start-with-shell' off?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

During a debug session (Debug|Simulator) I got this.  How do I set 'start-with-shell' off?  (I have looked and can't find any docs on how to do this).

```
[Session started at 2011-03-10 09:05:22 -0800.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1510) (Wed Sep 22 02:45:02 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 1734.
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
pthread_mutexattr_destroy$UNIX2003 called from function pthreadMutexAlloc in image PointsEncodeDecode.
If you are encountering this problem running a simulator binary within gdb, make sure you 'set start-with-shell off' first.
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
kill
quit

The Debugger has exited with status 0.(gdb)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App crashes with 4.2 iPhone simulator 'set start-with-shell off'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271480/app-crashes-with-4-2-iphone-simulator-set-start-with-shell-off), [valgrind and iOS SDK 4.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599462/valgrind-and-ios-sdk-4-2) and various others...

Comment: Yep, I saw that... didn't work for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this issue since I updated to XCode 3.2.5 with iOS 4.2

My problem came from native librairies I was using, that needed to be recompiled under iOS4. It seems that this iOS version is not fully binary compatible with the previous one...

Otherwise, try the new version of XCode 4 and iOS4.3 to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Hi rockeye... tried XCode 4 and it made things worse... it found files that I had deleted two weeks ago from my app... I'm going to try it again and do a Clean... other than that, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Reset all the simulators. From one version to another, they might have kept some corrupted dependencies or else. If it doesn't work, use the desperate solution : try to remove completely XCode from your computer, and reinstall it.

Comment: How do you "reset" the simulators?  I know how to clean the dependencies, etc, but not how to reset the simulators.

Comment: OK, figured out how to reset the simulators... I did that, and it didn't help... I'm going to close this and re-open it because I have a slightly different message this time... thanks for your help.